# Displaying images to a View

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am going through the following [tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/ImageIOGuide/imageio_source/ikpg_source.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005462-CH218-SW3). I need to get thumbnail images of a large image. According to the tutorial the following method does it.

```
CGImageRef MyCreateThumbnailImageFromData (NSData * data, int imageSize)
```

note: look at the tutorial if you need the full code for this method

My questions are;

1.) i have a URL `http://www.myimage.com/smile.jpg` , and i need to resize it to a thumbnail. I don't undestand what is the `NSData * data` parameter. All what i have is a String URL. So how can i pass my URL to this method programatically ?

2.) The above method returns a `CGImageRef` But i need a UIImage so i could add it to a UIIMageVIew and then display it in my project. So how can i use `CGImageRef` to display images in my project ?

3.) The images i am downloading are very big, 2MB or more. By making it to appear in a thumbnail size, will it reduce the time taken to load the image to the view ?

Comment: 1 & 2 are just programming problems you'll figure out but #3 is a bigger problem - you need to download it to resize it but why download 2MB on a phone just to resize to a thumbnail?  Instead do it server side or create a service proxy to do it and cache it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets go through this, step by step:

1) An `NSData` object is a wrapper for an array of bytes, or `char *`. This is the raw bytes of the image you need.

2) A `CGImageRef` is `CoreGraphics`'s way of representing an image, which can be converted to a `UIImage` with the selector `+imageWithCGImage:`. Generally speaking, you have more fine control over the image with a `CGImageRef`.

3) Converting these images to a thumbnail will not reduce the time it takes to download. The file must first be downloaded to memory before it is converted.

Example of how to use your function:

```
int myImageSize = .... // do what you need to to figure out the size of the image
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:MyCreateThumbnailImageFromData([NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myimage.com/smile.jpg"]], myImageSize)];
```

This, however will block the user interface, consider using GCD or NSURLConnection instead of `-dataWithContentsOfURL:`.

EDIT: Example with GCD:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
    __block UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:MyCreateThumbnailImageFromData([NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myimage.com/smile.jpg"]], myImageSize)];

    [myImageView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImage:) withObject:myImage waitUntilDone:NO];
});
```

Comment: For #3 consider doing it server side or creating a service if possible that caches it.

Comment: True, but that is not what is asked in the OP. I do agree the way he is trying to do this is a bit clunky, but I worked with what I was given.

Comment: +1 - makes sense.  Just wanted to add on to the answer.  Not sure if it's an option for him ...

Comment: :@ I am she. What did you mean by using GCD. Can you illustrate how to do it ?

Comment: @shajem done, if this answer helped you, remember to click the accept button next to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSData* theData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:@"http://www.myimage.com/smile.jpg"];
UIImage *theImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(128, 96));
[theImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 128, 96)];
UIImage *myThumbnail = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImageView *myThumbnailView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myThumbnail];
```

EDIT for asynchronous approach:

in your header file:

```
NSURLConnection* connection;
NSMutableData* data;

- (void)loadImageFromURL:(NSURL*)url;
```

in your implementation file:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myimage.com/smile.jpg"]];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

- (void)loadImageFromURL:(NSURL*)url {

    if (![NSThread isMainThread]) {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(loadImageFromURL:) withObject:url waitUntilDone:NO];
        return;
    }
    if (connection!=nil) { [connection release]; }

    if (data!=nil) { [data release]; }

    NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
    connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self]; 

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)theConnection didReceiveData:(NSData *)incrementalData {
    if (data==nil) { data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:4096]; } 
    [data appendData:incrementalData];
}



- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)theConnection {

    [connection release];
    connection=nil;

    UIImage *theImage    = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(128, 96));
    [theImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 128, 96)];
    UIImage *myThumbnail = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIImageView *myThumbnailView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myThumbnail];

    [data release];
    data=nil;
}
```

Comment: In the above question the author says to use `GCD or NSURLConnection instead of -dataWithContentsOfURL:`. So how can i do that in your code ?

Comment: Check out http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/ for asynchronous approach to get the data.

Comment: yeah, i went through it. the sample project didn't even run